# Reduce a string using grammar-like rules

Tags: java, performance

I've got a program in Java which simplifies input string using grammar-like rules. Length of string is up to 200 and number of rules is up to 300. In big cases it works too slow, so I need some advice on time optimization of the code.

Example input: `4 4; a b a b; a b -> b; a b -> c; b a -> a; c c -> b`

Program show all the simple chars that can be received from the input string `a b a b` using the rules. For this example it is `b c`. For string of length 155 and number of rules 92 the algorithm should work 0.05 seconds faster.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    static int n, p;
    static String input;
    String[] textStr;
    static BufferedReader buff;
    static Map<String, Set<String>> cache = new HashMap();
    static Map<String, ArrayList<Character>> rules = new HashMap();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        buff  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{
            String tem = buff.readLine();
            String textStr[] = tem.split("\\s+");
            n = Integer.parseInt(textStr[0]);
            p = Integer.parseInt(textStr[1]);
            tem = buff.readLine();
            input = tem.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            for(int i = 0; i < p; i++){
                tem = buff.readLine();
                textStr = tem.split("\\s+");
                Character cl = textStr[0].charAt(0);
                Character fa = textStr[1].charAt(0);
                Character re = textStr[2].charAt(0);
                if(!rules.containsKey(cl+" "+fa)){
                    rules.put(cl + " " + fa, new ArrayList());
                }
                rules.get(cl+" "+fa).add(re);
            }
            Set<String> temp = simplify(input);
            List<String> te = new ArrayList<>(temp);
            Collections.sort(te);
            for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
                System.out.print(te.get(i)+" ");
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        finally {
            try {
                buff.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    public static Set<String> simplify(final String in) {
        if(cache.containsKey(in)){
            return(cache.get(in));
        }
        Set<String> ret = new HashSet<>();
        if (in.length() == 1) {
            ret.add(in);
            return ret;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < in.length(); i++) {
            String head = in.substring(0, i);
            String tail = in.substring(i);
            for (String c2 : simplify(tail)) {
                for (String c1 : simplify(head)) {
                    ArrayList<Character> rep = rules.get(c1+" "+ c2);
                    if (rep != null) {
                        for (Character c : rep) {
                            ret.add(c.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cache.put(in, ret);
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question further by explaining the example rules?

Comment: @Chantz for example rule "a b b" means that if there is a pair "ab" in the input string this pair can be replaced with "b"

Comment: Oh. Ok. So you have 2 rules which have same input `a b` but different output `b` & `c`. What decides which reduction rule to pick when?

Comment: Why is the output not `b` for the example? If `a b` can be converted to `c` and `c c` can be converted to `b`, why is `a b a b` not `c c` and then `b`?

Answer (score 2):

`n` is unused.

You write to it here:

```
        n = Integer.parseInt(textStr[0]);
```

But you don't do anything with it.